# How to embed sox library with pyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, setup-project, sox

I am making a GUI based program using pyQT (python), and some of my sub program is being developed seperatly [using sox library](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

I am currently having issue in integrating both of things, actually pyQT is cross platform, and sox is cross platform too, but how can I send the package installation code of sox too inside the package/setup I would make at last. (sox is not python library).

Please guide me on this topic.

Comment: hel, early reply needed

Comment: what you really need to get ? .. Do you want to import sox lib in pyqt app ? or you want to embed sox ?

Comment: whatever way possible. i just need to run sox library over a voice recorded using my recorder (python library) in pyQT.